# Exclude imported vendor files from linting with stylelint

Tags: webpack, stylelint

I want to properly exclude imported vendor files from linting with stylelint. I have this `app.scss`:

```css
@import '~bootstrap';
@import '~bootstrap-vue';

body {
  background: gray;
}
```

and this `.stylelintrc.json`:

```js
{
  "extends": "stylelint-config-standard"
}
```

During compilation (with Webpack Encore) I get over 8000 warnings, for example this:

```
 warning  in ./assets/scss/app.scss

Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
Warning

(9998:1) Expected selector ".input-group-sm > .custom-range" to come before selector ".input-group > .form-control-plaintext + .custom-range" (no-descending-specificity)
```

What I want is 0 warnings and 0 errors. What is the correct way to achieve this?

## Note

I already tried a lot, for example this:

```css
/* stylelint-disable */
@import '~bootstrap';
@import '~bootstrap-vue';
/* stylelint-enable */
```

With this the 8000 warnings are gone but I get another warning:

```
(11596:1) Unexpected duplicate selector "body", first used at line 56 (no-duplicate-selectors)
```

I also tried to accomplish what I want by editing `.stylelintrc.json` using the following options: `ignoreFiles`, `ignorePath`, `severity`, `defaultSeverity`. I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: How do you use stylelint with webpack? via stylelint-webpack-plugin?

Comment: @felixmosh Yes, exactly, via stylelint-webpack-plugin. Does that help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What actually solved my problem is to add the styles which override bootstrap styles to the disabled styles.

```css
/* stylelint-disable */
@import '~bootstrap';
@import '~bootstrap-vue';
body {
  background: gray;
}
/* stylelint-enable */
```

Answer (score 1):

From [docs](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/configuration#stylelintignore)

> You can use a .stylelintignore file (or point to another ignore patterns file) to ignore specific files.
>
> These files will be excluded from the files glob before the file system is check at all, so it is an efficient method for ignoring lots of files.

So add a `.stylelintignore` file with paths to ignore,

```
node_modules/
```

Comment: I can't see any difference to my not working solution using comments to disable styles with: /* stylelint-disable */

Comment: `.stylelintignore` doesn't work for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69936080/stylelint-how-to-ignore-files-and-folders-ignorefiles-and-stylelintignore-do

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same issue using a combination of `postcss-easy-import` and `stylelint`.  The problem for me was loading `stylelint` as a direct plugin of PostCSS when it should've been loaded as a plugin of `postcss-easy-import`.

#### PostCSS Config Before

```js
module.exports = ( cfg ) => {
  return {
    plugins: [
      require( 'postcss-dart-sass' )({
        includePaths: [ ... ]
      }),
      require( 'postcss-easy-import' )({
        prefix: '_',
        extensions: ['.scss', '.css']
      }),
      require( 'stylelint' )({
        cache: true,
        cacheLocation: '/tmp/.stylelintcache',
        ignorePath: '.stylelintignore'
      })
    ]
  };
};
```

#### PostCSS Config After

```js
module.exports = ( cfg ) => {
  return {
    plugins: [
      require( 'postcss-dart-sass' )({
        includePaths: [ ... ]
      }),
      require( 'postcss-easy-import' )({
        prefix: '_',
        extensions: ['.scss', '.css'],
        plugins: [
          require( 'stylelint' )({
            cache: true,
            cacheLocation: '/tmp/.stylelintcache',
            ignorePath: '.stylelintignore'
          })
        ]
      })
    ]
  };
};
```